# jekyll build on debian 8, gem not found

Tags: ruby, rubygems, debian, jekyll

I try to build my site with jekyll on vps, and i receve the followind error:

```
    jekyll build
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require': cannot load such file -- jekyll-paginate (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:30:in `block in require_gems'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:27:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:27:in `require_gems'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:19:in `conscientious_require'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:97:in `setup'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:49:in `initialize'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `new'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `process'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `call'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.0/bin/jekyll:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

i have found the problem is the different location oh jekyll and gem package

```
whereis jekyll
jekyll: /usr/local/bin/jekyll
whereis gem
gem: /usr/bin/gem2.1 /usr/bin/gem /usr/share/man/man1/gem.1.gz
```

i have installed jekyll by gem and ruby package from debian repos.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a `gem install jekyll-paginate` will do the trick.

Comment: Thx you so much, it's work now! I just can't understand why it wasn't installed with jekyll

Comment: Cool. Thx to approve the answer.